# Why do the different methods share the same argument in a Ruby Class?

Tags: ruby

I saw the following program in Beginning Ruby, and can not figure out the purposes of `set_first_name(first_name)` and `set_last_name(last_name)` and why the two methods `set_first_name` and `set_last_name` use the same argument `name`, because I think that name includes `first_name` and `last_name`.

```
class Person
  def initialize(name)
    set_name(name)
  end

  def name
    @first_name + ' ' + @last_name
  end

  def set_name(name)
    first_name, last_name = name.split(/\s+/)
    set_first_name(first_name)
    set_last_name(last_name)
  end

  def set_first_name(name)
    @first_name = name
  end

  def set_last_name(name)
    @last_name = name
  end
end

p = Person.new("Fred Bloggs")
puts p.name
```

Comment: I can see the confusion - the class `Person` has a method named `name`, and uses the parameter `name` to `set_first_name` and `set_last_name`. Yes, this is a little sloppy for an intro text, but the ruby parser sees these as completely different entities. It would be clearer if the parameter name to `set_first_name` was `first_name`, and same with `set_last_name` but would still function all the same.

Comment: This is one of those times when you are over-thinking it. The parameter value could be a random string, or it could be more indicative. It's not that important really, when you think about it, since you understood what the purpose and meaning of the parameter was. In your own code it's OK to agonize over the exact terminology but, really, don't bog down on this. There are a lot bigger issues you'll encounter in programming.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh.  That is a horrible introduction.  There's a fair amount of magic that goes into determining if "name" is a local variable or method.  And depending on what you do, you can switch it from one to the other.

Add the following method to your class:

```
def test
  puts name
  name = "Bob"
  puts name
  puts self.name
end
```

Then run it like this:

```
p = Person.new('Jane Doe')
p.test
```

You'll get the following output:

```
Jane Doe
Bob
Jane Doe
```

What's happening is that at first `name` isn't found as a local variable so it looks for a method (and will look up through the ancestors/modules of the class as well if there are any).  Then we assign a value to name.  Which makes my head hurt, but is legal.  On the next puts `name` now refers to that local variable.  We can get back to the method by specifying `self.name`.

Honestly, as the others have noted this class is poorly named (heh, pun intended? :).  It's best to avoid this confusion if you can.

David Black has a book called The Well-Grounded Rubyist.  Chapter 5 in particular goes over this in great detail.  It's a great book in general.  No affiliation just a happy customer.

http://www.manning.com/black2/